# remote execution in sikuli

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, sikuli

I have an integrated selenium/sikuili automation project which I would like to run on windows agent here is the scenario: Machine (A) contains the source code Machine (B) is the agent test runner machine that has selenium grid running on it, when machine a run the test, selenium test is successfully triggered on machine B but when sikuili runs it's trying to search elements on machine(A). anyone has any idea how could I fix this issue.

thank you all in advance

Comment: I was looking for this too, but question is still open. Did you find solution?

Comment: Hi @doge I fixed it using Jenkins, what I have basically done is creating a salve agent and point it to a remote machine(where I actually build and run my project) just made sure that I had sikuili as var in my remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use selenium grid extensions:
https://github.com/sterodium/selenium-grid-extensions

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using Jenkins, what I have basically done is creating a salve agent and point it to a remote machine(where I actually build and run my project) just made sure that I had sikuili as var in my remote machine.